# How can I remove the cooldown for a command after an asyncio event is over?

Tags: discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

How can I cross-command check/compare the cooldown with an asyncio function?
I have a command in my bot which sends an embed and after x-seconds/minutes/hours edits the embed. At the same time there is then a command which gives the possibility to send a message. After a single execution this command should not be usable for the user as long as the `asyncio` event is still running or the embed is not edited again. How can I make this happen?

***The answer code which should then have the cooldown for the remaining `asyncio` time:***

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def answer(self, ctx, text: str):
        await ctx.channel.send(text, delete_after=0)
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.author.send(f"**{ctx.author.mention}, you chose: {text}**")
```

***The command which sends the embed:***

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def trivia_c(self, ctx):

        e = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.gold())
        e.title = "New question, new luck."
        e.description = "**When was Steve Jobs born?**"
        e.add_field(name="1️⃣", value="02/24/1955", inline=False)
        e.add_field(name="2️⃣", value="03/24/1955", inline=False)
        e.add_field(name="3️⃣", value="02/24/1965", inline=False)
        e.set_footer(text="You have x-x to answer this question.", icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)
        e.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        question = await ctx.send(embed=e)

        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await self.answer.reset_cooldown(ctx)

        e2 = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.gold())
        [etc.]
        await question.edit(embed=e2)
```

As you can see I already tried to reset the cooldown with `await self.answer.reset_cooldown(ctx)` but what am I missing in the `answer`command itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands get a cooldown whenever they're used, you're not actually using the command so there's no actuall cooldown, you're resetting the cooldown of 0. You can simply enable/disable the command for the "asyncio time"

```py
# Before sleeping
self.answer.enabled = False
# Sleeping
await asyncio.sleep(10)
# After sleeping
self.answer.enabled = True
```

You should also have an error handler for the command

```py
@answer.error
async def answer_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.DisabledCommand):
        await ctx.send("Please wait! You can't use this command yet") # Unfornatelly you can't add the time left
```

#### Reference:

- [`Command.enabled`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=enable#discord.ext.commands.Command.enabled)
- [`commands.DisabledCommand`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=disabledcommand#discord.ext.commands.DisabledCommand)